# Unable to get a readable xlsx file generated with SheetJS js-xlsx library

Tags: javascript, api, rest, xlsx, sheetjs

I want to get a readable xlsx file... I have written the following code with the library SheetJS xlsx, however I am missing something as I am unable to dowload a readable file

```
const download = async (req, res) => {
    let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    wb.Props = {
      Title: 'Investments',
      Subject: 'A test of subject',
      Author: 'Finanze',
      CreatedDate: new Date(),
    };
    wb.SheetNames.push('investments');
    var ws_data = [
      ['S', 'h', 'e', 'e', 't', 'J', 'S'],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ];
    var ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(ws_data);
    wb.Sheets['investments'] = ws;

    res.setHeader(
      'Content-Type',
      'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    );

    const wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {
      bookType: 'xlsx',
      type: 'binary',
    });

    res.send(wbout);
    res.status(200).end();
};

router.get('/download', download);
```

[image]

Comment: Your xlsx code seems to work fine, so maybe its a problem with sending the response. You haven't mentioned any details about this. However, perhaps you need to `await res.send(wbout)` ?